# Issue with selenium java automation on testing server where noe element is found after login

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to do a automation test on my companies website(Testing Server). The first page is login page which gets automated perfectly with the given ID, PASS and OTP. The next page after Login opens is Dashboard page and it opens in Same window. Now on this dashboard page whatever I tried I am not able to find any element with selenium. I always get "NoSuchElementException".

------What I have Tried-----

1.Firstly I contacted my devs they said our website is a React Web App so try and learn how to automate react app.
I tried Several things like handling AJax request, but nothing worked.

2.Then i tried using selenium wait(Implicit and Explicit),Thread sleep which also didn't worked.

3.Tried to see if there is any iFrame or any window swithching  but there was no such thing.
On the dashboard page used assertion to verify the title and I get the result as TRUE so selenium is on the same dashboard page.

4. Now my devs says that try to store token may be there is some token issue
   But this I don't understand what the actually meant.

Below is my code...

```
    public class Test1 {
        WebDriverWait wait = null;
        WebDriver driver = null;
        WebElement searchField = null;
        @Parameters("browser")
        @BeforeClass 
        public void beforeclass(@Optional("chrome") String browser){
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","./Drivers/chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();        
            driver.get("WEBSITE");
            wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(25));
        } 
            
        @Test
            public void login() throws InterruptedException  {
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                WebElement searchField = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='sc-kDTinF hjZgsN']"));
                searchField.sendKeys("MYUSERID");
                WebElement searchFiel = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='password']"));
                searchFiel.sendKeys("MYPASS");
                WebElement searchbtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='button']")); 
                searchbtn.click();
                WebElement srch = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@aria-label='Please enter verification code. Digit 1'][@autocomplete='off']"));  
                srch.sendKeys("1"); 
                WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@aria-label='Digit 2']"));
                search.sendKeys("2");
                WebElement sarch = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@aria-label='Digit 3']"));
                sarch.sendKeys("3");
                WebElement sch = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@aria-label='Digit 4']"));
                sch.sendKeys("4");
                WebElement serchbtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='button']"));   
                serchbtn.click();
        }
        @Test 
            public void calendarSetting() {
                String actualtitle = driver.getTitle();
                Assert.assertEquals(actualtitle, "SafetyConnect");          
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("sc-hiCibw")));
                WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.className("sc-hiCibw"));
                ele.click();
        
            }
}
```

HTML AND EXCEPTION FILE LINK

[HTML AND EXCEPTION FILE](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NhsQCu4YlCDoTCq9myJmGgJayq_HDyHU?usp=share_link)

Comment: If possible share the application URL else share the exception and HTML code as well.

Comment: Hello, Thankyou for reply I have added the HTML and EXCEPTION file in the link please checkSInce the app is on dev server it is not possible to provide the app URL